# "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webdriver (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for webdriver"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I couldn't able to install webdriver using terminal.
Note I am using windows 11, PyCharm IDE.

The error I'm getting is :

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webdriver (from versions: none) 
ERROR: No matching distribution found for webdriver
```

Please help me out I am not getting any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably referring to the [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) library.

For installing it, you need to execute:

```bash
pip install -U selenium
```

in your shell terminal according to the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)

Comment: Selenium is already Installed but I want to install Webdriver for chrome. That's what  I am getting issues.

Comment: what webdriver are you referring to?

Comment: Chrome Webdriver